# Trigger that inserts row into log table on insert or delete in a persons table compiled with errors

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a persons table with a name and id as well as a logs table with attributes who and what.
I want to insert into the logs table when I delete or insert into the persons table.

This is what I have so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER add_del
  BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE ON persons
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    IF INSERTING THEN
      INSERT INTO logs (who, what) VALUES (name, 'Insert into persons');
    ELSE
      INSERT INTO logs (who, what) VALUES (name, 'Delete from persons');
    END IF;
  END;
  /
```

Why does this compile with the error:

Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

Comment: It just says
Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

Comment: If you are using SQL*Plus, type `show errors` in order to get a listing of the errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't post the error, I have to guess.  My guess is that the problem is that `name` is not a valid identifier in this context.  You need to reference either `:new.name` or `:old.name`.  `:old.name` will be `NULL` on an insert while `:new.name` will be `NULL` on a delete so I'm assuming you want something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER add_del
  BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE ON persons
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING THEN
    INSERT INTO logs (who, what) VALUES (:new.name, 'Insert into persons');
  ELSE
    INSERT INTO logs (who, what) VALUES (:old.name, 'Delete from persons');
  END IF;
END;
```