# Trigger that inserts into a table when a new account is opened

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
customers:
+------------+--------------+ 
| cid        | Name         | 
+------------+--------------+ 
| 1          | Bob          |
| 2          | John         | 
| 3          | Jane         | 
+------------+--------------+ 
accounts:
+------------+--------------+ 
| aid        | type         | 
+------------+--------------+ 
| 1          | Checking     |
| 2          | Saving       | 
| 3          | Checking     | 
+------------+--------------+ 
transactions:
+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+ 
| tid        | cid          | aid          | type         |
+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+ 
| 1          | 1            | 1            | Open         |
| 2          | 2            | 3            | Open         |
| 3          | 1            | 2            | Open         |
| 4          | 2            | 3            | Deposit      |
+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

I am trying to write a trigger that writes to a logs table when a new account is successfully opened.

Right now I have this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER acc_opened
BEFORE INSERT ON transactions
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    c_name customers.name%TYPE;
BEGIN
    IF :new.type = 'Open' THEN
        SELECT name into c_name
        FROM customers c
        WHERE c.cid = :new.cid;

        INSERT INTO logs (who, what) VALUES (c_name, 'An account has been opened');
END;
/
```

The code that I have doesn't work and don't know where to go from here.

The trigger completes, but when it fires, I get this error message:

PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following: (begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma raise return select update while with    << continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback savepoint set sql execut commit forall merge pipe purge

Comment: Can you clarify what "doesn't work" means?  Are you getting an error?  If so, what error?  Is this a compilation error or a runtime error?

Comment: Sorry, just added the errors.

Answer (score 0):

As with your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756110/trigger-that-inserts-row-into-log-table-on-insert-or-delete-in-a-persons-table-c), if you want to refer to a particular column of the new row of data, you need to use the `:new` pseudo-record.  So, at a minimum,

```
SELECT cid 
  INTO c_id
  FROM transactions t
 WHERE t.aid = aid;
```

would need to be

```
SELECT cid 
  INTO c_id
  FROM transactions t
 WHERE t.aid = :new.aid;
```

Beyond that, are you sure that the row exists in the `transactions` table before the row is inserted into the `accounts` tale?  Assuming that you have normal foreign key constraints, I would generally expect that you would insert a row into the `accounts` table before inserting the row into the `transactions` table.

The name `transactions` also seems pretty odd.  If that is really just mapping the customer ID to the account ID, `transactions` seems like a rather poor name.  If that table actually stores transactions, I'm not sure why it would have a customer ID.  But if it does store transactions, there must be some other table that maps customers to accounts.

In your updated trigger, you are missing the `END IF` statement

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER acc_opened
  BEFORE INSERT ON transactions
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  c_name customers.name%TYPE;
BEGIN
  IF :new.type = 'Open' 
  THEN
    SELECT name 
      into c_name
      FROM customers c
     WHERE c.cid = :new.cid;

     INSERT INTO logs (who, what) 
       VALUES (c_name, 'An account has been opened');
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: I absolutely agree. I did try it with :new.aid as well, but it still wouldn't work. The professor gave us this schema and it is very poorly designed... You are right in saying that it should insert into accounts first before transactions. But the schema offers no way in getting the customer information from the accounts table.

Comment: @user1378863 - "Still wouldn't work" doesn't tell us much-- are you saying that you're getting the same error on the same line?  Or are you getting a different error?  Or are you saying something else?  If you insert first into the `accounts` table and then into the `transactions` table and `transactions` is actually mapping customers to accounts rather than storing transactions, the trigger would need to be defined on the `transactions` table not on the `accounts` table.

Comment: And the `transactions` table does store transactions, but it is the only table that maps `customers` to `accounts`...

Comment: Sorry, I am getting a "no data found" error since it has not added a record to `transactions` yet.

Comment: @user1378863 - Then you're not going to be able to get the customer data from a trigger on the `accounts` table.  Is there something in the `transactions` table that identifies the transaction as an account opening?

Comment: There was a mistake in the schema and is now a new column for type of transaction. So there is now a column for opening an account. I attempted to write a trigger, but once again it doesn't work. I've edited the table as well as added the error. It would be much appreciated if you can help figure out why it isn't working.

Comment: Currently, you're missing the END IF after the INSERT statement.

Comment: @user1378863 - As Codo indicated, you are missing the `END IF`.