# Creating a record history table - How do I create a record on creation?

Tags: oracle

For a project, I want to have a "History" table for my records. I have two tables for this (example) system:

```
RECORDS
    ID
    NAME
    CREATE_DATE

RECORDS_HISTORY
    ID
    RECORDS_ID
    LOG_DATE
    LOG_TYPE
    MESSAGE
```

When I insert a record into `RECORDS`, how can I automatically create an associated entry in `RECORDS_HISTORY` where `RECORDS_ID` is equal to the newly inserted `ID` in `RECORDS`?

I currently have a sequence on the `ID` in `RECORDS` to automatically increment when a new row is inserted, but I am unsure how to prepopulate a record in `RECORDS_HISTORY` that will look like this for each newly created (not updated) record.

```
INSERT INTO RECORDS_HISTORY (RECORDS_ID, LOG_DATE, LOG_TYPE, MESSAGE) VALUES (<records.id>, sysdate(), 'CREATED', 'Record created')
```

How can I create this associated `_HISTORY` record on creation?

Comment: You want a trigger.

Comment: Like @a_horse_with_no_name said, triggers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756110/trigger-that-inserts-row-into-log-table-on-insert-or-delete-in-a-persons-table-c
or
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/26953/trigger-to-automatically-add-values-to-a-table-in-oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention the DB you are working with. I assume its Oracle. The most obvious answer is: Use a "On Insert Trigger". You even can get back the ID (sequence) from the insert statement into table RECORDS. Disadvantages of this solution: Triggers are kinda "hidden" code, can slow down processes on massive inserts and you consume like double diskspace on storing data partially redundant. What if RECORDS got updated or deleted? Can that happen and do you have to take care of that as well? The big question is: What is your goal? 
There are proved historisation concepts around. Have a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension